# A side toolbar like natively proposed on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-7, launcher

I'm working on Windows 7 and I miss the toolbar like Windows Vista (those toolbars you can place on bottom, left, right or top of the screen to display folder contents).
I've tested many and many softwares, from most known to less ones, spending hours in settings panels, without finding one that could assume the same behaviours.

My requirements are, on Windows 7 x64 :

- ability to be docked at the left of the screen
- ability to be shown/hidden automaticaly on mouse contact
- ability to be displayed "over" the desktop
- ability to automaticaly display the content of one or many folders
- ability to display the folder name as a title on top of the displayed contents
- ability to sort alphabeticaly the displayed items

Many softwares do that, but perhaps the more important that no one do :

- ability to display permanently the mini-icon and the label of the displayed content on one line

The very best one I found to do this is [OldBar](http://www.ondanera.net/oldbar.aspx), but it has many huge bugs at the moment that makes it unuseable (I wrote to its author to list them).
I don't know if OldBar will be updated (last update on 2012), so do you know a software or a way that could satisfy my needs ?

Comment: By toolbar you mean taskbar?

Comment: Have you tried copying the sidebar binary from a Vista installation to Win7?

Comment: @Alejandro : !!!! No... Is that just possible ? What would be the system items involved ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything like that, but trying to copy the sidebar files and registering them seems like a nice attempt. Look at this tutorial: http://www.win2008workstation.com/installing-the-vista-sidebar/. While that attempts to install gadgets into Win2008 it may help for 7 too.

Comment: @Alejandro : Thank you, but you seems to talk about the sidebar and not the toolbars (those you can place on bottom, left, right or top of the screen)